# Snap one (active) vertex in a selected curve + move all vertices in curve by snap amount?

Tags: snapping

I have four vertices arranged in a curve. Is it possible to snap just one point in the selected curve (e.g. the backmost one) to some vertex on another mesh and automatically translate all the other vertices in the curve by the same XYZ distance? For instance, in the image, I would like to snap the selected vertex to the nearest one on the gray mesh (X-ray mode is on), and also translate the 3 vertices on the same edge-loop by the same distance. Thanks!

PS Since I just experimented with it: **I would like the active vertex to snap** and the rest to translate. My test seemed to snap the middle vertex in the curve instead.

PPS Seems by default, the vertex nearest the snap destination will snap. I wonder if there's a more intuitive way to control this.

[image]

Answer (score 1, accepted):

In this example, 'Snap With' is set to 'Active' and 'Snap To' is set to 'Vertex'.

The snap has been set to 'Project onto Self', and set to work in translation, rotation, and scale.

The Pivot has been set to '3D Cursor'.. although of course, that wouldn't matter if you were just translating..

[image]

In the illustration, the active vertex starts off as the one at the bottom, and is then switched to the one at the other end.

When you move, rotate, (or scale) the active vertex, the other selected vertices will follow.

Note: the rotation has to be constrained to an axis to work.

Comment: I used the imprecise method I mentioned in my question on what I specifically asked about (eyes), but tried your method for the same character's mouth. Didn't realize there were ot her options hidden in that little Snap icon. Thanks; works like a charm!

Comment: It may be worth noting that if one uses Alt+click to select an edge loop, their cursor needs to be nearer the desired active vertex for max efficiency. One may already be working at close enough zoom to preclude this, but still.

Comment: Hi, @Nintendraw. You mean the vert you want to make active may be out of reach by the time you've made your selection? Yes, you do have to think ahead..Blender's snap system is far from perfect.. some moves are easier with, for instance, a 3DMax-type system. But it's worth checking out the manual and playing with all the mystery options, when you've got a spare moment.